# Download a file via php

Tags: php, download

I would like to know how to get a file when a site sends me download header (for example :http://www.exploit-db.com/download/1) how I can  using PHP.

I used this function to get the file : file_get_contents('http://www.exploit-db.com/download/1');

but the contents are not that I want >> saved contents : �
:|

Answer (score 0):

Try the wget function instead wget('http://www.exploit-db.com/download/1');

Comment: thanks for your answer my friend but the server is limited and the host is shared , i want to just using php

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code, and that cause 301 redirection:

`file_get_contents('http://www.exploit-db.com/download/1/');`

With trailing slash